# How to add users to SharePoint Groups in different SPO sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I'm trying to execute the script located below, but I'm getting the error:

> System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Mi
>   crosoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.
>      at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)

The script is located here:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-add-users-to-1d3e69f9

I have both assemblies on the folder where the script is located at:

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime`

Could you please guys help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the assemblies directly, and have the latest version installed.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

If you do not have these you will need to install them from Microsoft.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038

Comment: I have.. but still getting the same error... I can execute other scripts using csom.. the problem is not related with assemblies

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? It should be contained in the `$error` variable, and you can pull it by going `$Error[0].StackTrace`.

Comment: @PeterSmp -- I would also check you have the latest CSOM assemblies available. It may be looking for something that is not in an older release.

Comment: Glad to hear. Don't forget to answer your own question with the solution if mine didn't fix it.